# Combining strings command and grep: how to limit results to null-terminated strings

Tags: shell, grep, string

I have a feeling that it is `strings` which is thwarting my efforts here.
The binary files I want to use `strings` on unfortunately yield several matches per file, even though it is a 100% rule that exactly one of these contains the string with a `NUL` character at the end. And THIS is the string I want. I'm also working this way to make sure that **false positives are eliminated** from the beginning.

Unfortunately, it seems that `strings` cannot be taught to preserve the null-bytes so I can `grep` for `some_expression\0`.

Sample line: (simplified)

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -print0 | xargs -0 strings -fwn 3 | grep -w 'XYZ'
```

If `strings` could be told to *keep* the `\0` characters, it would even allow something like `... | grep -w 'XYZ[^[:print:]]'` at the end of the pipe later.
But of course, `grep` is powerless whenever the preceding command in the pipe has already *eliminated* the '\0'.

I've even thought of a (fairly ugly) way to tackle this problem by `tr`'ing each '\0' character to something like '\177' (decimal 255) in the whole file that's being processed.
But that would probably yield too many false positives.

Any better solutions out there?

<sub>**Additional note**: Although this question only covers the most common case (`NUL`), an optimum solution would define as one that is suitable for easy adaptation on other non-printable characters used for string termination as well.</sub>

Comment: I can't test/write it all up right now, but what about piping the files through 'od -c' or xxd, from which you could then grep the corresponding codes?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I should see some sample line first instead of blind fiddling. Plus, it would be great to keep using `strings`, because with big files it will already have filtered so much garbage before `grep` even gets its first attempt to process the content.

Comment: Would omitting `strings` and using something like `grep -waoP 'XYZ\x00'` work?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Indeed it would, however there appears to be a general problem with `\xAA` hex codes in the `grep `regex. Spotted lots of similar questions here on SE. Users occasionally had to work around it by `grep`ing for `'XYZ'$'\x00'`, i. e. using the built-in trickery of some (not all!) shells. Maybe hex codes in `grep` will only work reliably in GNU `grep`? __Besides:__ `-a` is discouraged, as it might wreak havoc on a terminal due to the shell interpreting some of the control codes as actual ones. So these might clear your screen, deface output strings, insult your mother...;-)

Comment: Yes, some of these options are only supported by GNU grep. `-a` isn't a problem here, since we give grep the `-o` option; `-a` would only cause control codes to be displayed if your grep regexps matched control codes, which they won't. The `-P` option allows NUL to be specified as `\x00` in the regexp, as 4 ordinary characters, no shell magic required.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Well I always love to be as portable as possible. :) Thanks for the heads-up with `-o`, as I didn't consider it absolutely necessary. However, if it can eliminate said artifacts, I might include it in the `grep` options. __Besides__: I chose the NUL as most common case, but it might indeed be a `\x01` in another. So there'd be your control code, all of a sudden! :) That reads, the __ideal way__ would be to find a solution that will work a) without `-a` and b) for ALL `[^[:print:]]`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Well, actually I thought that if someone posts a solution for '\x00', I can also make this work for, say, '\x07'. Plus, iit was in fact a  matter of physical length of question title: now picture something like *"Combining strings command and grep: how to limit results to strings terminated by NUL or similar non-printable characters"* :-) Ugh. TL;DR. So I chose the most significant case and I am going to adapt similar cases accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Make `grep` do the work of `strings`. If you have GNU grep, pass the `-z` option to make it read null-delimited records instead of newline-delimited records. This will also match at the end of the file, but that should be ok in practice.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -print0 |
xargs -0 grep -Eoz '[[:print:]]{3,}$'
```

If you don't have GNU utilities, pass the file through `tr` to swap null bytes with newlines. While you're at it, make `tr` trash non-printable characters.

```
find . -type d -prune -o -type f -size +1024k -exec sh -c '
  for x; do
    <"$x" tr \\0\\n \\n\\0 | tr -dsC "[:print:]" \\n |
    grep ...
  done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: As usual, you're simply a magician. :-O Thank you so much. Had not the slightest idea that `tr` would even understand a whole set like `[[:print:]]`instead of mere dumb single characters (i. e. the purpose it would normally serve). Might take me a while to have your partially "golfed" solution broken down to things I can follow, but nevermind: I think I can master that on my own. Thanks again.