# Is there a variant of "strings" that only matches null-terminated C strings?

Tags: grep, string, search

I'm up against a situation that seems like it must already have an implemented solution somewhere, but I'm having a tough time finding one. I'm looking for something that functions more or less exactly like `strings` (from binutils) but that only matches if the run of printable characters also ends with a null byte. As an additional hitch, I need the hex offset printed alongside each match (a la `strings -tx`).

I've seen a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260463/combining-strings-command-and-grep-how-to-limit-results-to-null-terminated-stri) that asks how to do it with `grep`. I guess something like that could work, if I can find a way to get `grep` to also output the hex offset like `strings -tx` does. But it seems to me that there should exist, somewhere, a tool that already does this natively.

Comment: The actual [main loop of strings](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/binutils/strings.c#L517) isn't that crazy. If all else fails, I'll start hacking away at that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Building on that similar question, `grep` can output decimal offsets. You can convert them to hex with awk.

```
grep -Eboz '[[:print:]]{4,}$' inputfile |
awk '{i=index($0,":");printf "%7x %s\n",$0+0,substr($0,i+1)}'
```